# divide php mysql result left and right

Tags: php, css, while-loop

[image]

```
 $flag=0;
 if($q->num_rows > 0) :
     echo '<div id="testimonial">';
     while($r = $q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) :
         if($flag=0) :
              $class=test1; $flag=1;
         else :
              $class=test2; $flag=0;
         endif;

         echo '<div class="'.$class.'">';
           echo '<span class="left">';
           echo '<p>'.$r['compname'].'</p>';
           echo '<p>'.$r['position'].'</p>';
           echo '</span>';
           echo '<span class="right">';
           echo '<p>'.$r['testimonial'].'</p>';
           echo '</span>';
         echo '</div>';
     endwhile;
     echo '</div>';
 else :
     echo '<h1>Coming Soon</h1>';
 endif;
```

i want the result look like the picture! seems my php code doesnt work out the css class. its only showing 1 class `test1` when i echoing the result. so all the result left align.

Comment: `if($flag=0)` is an assignment and therefore always true. Use the comparison operator "=="

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($flag=0)
        ^ should be ==
```

This is easier though with:

```
$i = 0;
while (…) {
    $class = $i++ % 2 ? 'test1' : 'test2';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an assignment in your if statement instead of a comparison: `if($flag=0)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$class=test1; $flag=1;
       ^----^---
```

you're missing some quotes there too. As it stands now, you're trying to assign a constant named "test1" and "test2", which are most likely not defined, so they'll evaluate to an empty string.

Comment: This'll evaluate to the string `'test1'`, not an empty string. ...yeah, that's PHP. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 $flag=0;
 if($q->num_rows > 0) :
     echo '<div id="testimonial">';
     while($r = $q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) :
         if($flag==0) :
              $class='test1'; $flag=1;
         else :
              $class='test2'; $flag=0;
         endif;

         echo '<div class="'.$class.'">';
           echo '<span class="left">';
           echo '<p>'.$r['compname'].'</p>';
           echo '<p>'.$r['position'].'</p>';
           echo '</span>';
           echo '<span class="right">';
           echo '<p>'.$r['testimonial'].'</p>';
           echo '</span>';
         echo '</div>';
     endwhile;
     echo '</div>';
 else :
     echo '<h1>Coming Soon</h1>';
 endif;
```

This should work!